# Is there an API method in Slack-Api to set (change) Events API Request URLs so I can do this in code?

Tags: slack-api, slack

To use Events API for Slack App development, there is a setting for "Events API Request URLs" as described in [doc](https://api.slack.com/events-api):

> In the Events API, your Events API Request URL is the target location
>   where all the events your application is subscribed to will be
>   delivered, regardless of the team or event type.

There is a UI for changing the URL "manually" at `api.slack.com` under 
"Event Subscriptions" section in settings. There is also `url_verification` event after changing the Request URL described [here](https://api.slack.com/events-api#url_verification).

My question - Is there an API call (method) so I can update the endpoint (Request URL) from my server code?

For example, in Facebook API there is a call named `subscriptions` where I can change webhook URL after initial setup - [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/app/subscriptions)

> Making a POST request with the callback_url, verify_token, and object
>   fields will reactivate the subscription.

PS. To give a background, this is needed for development using outbound tunnel with dynamic endpoint URL, e.g. ngrok free subscription. By the way, ngrok is referenced in sample "onboarding" app by slack [here](https://github.com/slackapi/onboarding-example)

**Update**. I checked Microsoft Bot Framework, and they seems to use RTM (Real Time Messaging) for slack which doesn't require Request URL setup, and not Events API. Same time, e.g. for Facebook they (MS Bot) instruct me to manually put their generated URL to webhook settings of a FB app, so there is no automation on that.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was originally asked, Slack has introduced [app manifests](https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests), which enable API calls to change app configurations. This can be used to update URLs and other parameters, or create/delete apps.

At the time of writing, the manifest / manifest API is in beta:

> Beta API — this API is in beta, and is subject to change without the usual notice period for changes.

so the this answer *might not* exactly fit the latest syntax as they make changes.

---

**A programatic workflow might look as follows:**

1. Pull a 'template' manifest from an existing version of the application, with most of the settings as intended (scopes, name, etc.)
2. Change parts of the manifest to meet the needs of development
3. Verify the manifest
4. Update a slack app or create a new one for testing

### API List

[Basic API list](https://api.slack.com/methods?filter=apps)

- Export a manifest as `JSON`: [`apps.manifest.export`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.export)
- Validate a manifest `JSON`: [`apps.manifest.validate`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.validate)
- Update an existing app: [`apps.manifest.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.update)
- Create a new app from manifest: [`apps.manifest.create`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.create)
- Delete an app: [`apps.manifest.delete`](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.delete)

Most of these API requests are [Tier 1 requests](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits#tier_t1), so only on the order of 1+ per minute.

### API Access

You'll need to create and maintain "App Configuration Tokens". They're created in the ["Your Apps"](https://api.slack.com/apps) dashboard. More info about them [here](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types).

### Example `NodeJS` Code

```js
const axios = require('axios');

// Change these values:
const TEMPLATE_APP_ID = 'ABC1234XYZ';
const PUBLIC_URL = 'https://www.example.com/my/endpoint';
let access = {
    slackConfigToken: "xoxe.xoxp-1-MYTOKEN",
    slackConfigRefreshToken: "xoxe-1-MYREFRESHTOKEN",
    slackConfigTokenExp: 1648550283
};

// Helpers ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get a new access token with the refresh token
async function refreshTokens() {
    let response = await axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/tooling.tokens.rotate?refresh_token=${access.slackConfigRefreshToken}`);
    if (response.data.ok === true) {
        access.slackConfigToken = response.data.token;
        access.slackConfigRefreshToken = response.data.refresh_token;
        access.slackConfigTokenExp = response.data.exp;
        console.log(access);
    } else {
        console.error('> [error] The token could not be refreshed. Visit https://api.slack.com/apps and generate tokens.');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

// Get an app manifest from an existing slack app
async function getManifest(applicationID) {
    const config = {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access.slackConfigToken}` }};
    let response = await axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/apps.manifest.export?app_id=${applicationID}`, config);
    if (response.data.ok === true) return response.data.manifest;
    else {
        console.error('> [error] Invalid could not get manifest:', response.data.error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

// Create a slack application with the given manifest
async function createDevApp(manifest) {
    const config = {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access.slackConfigToken}` }};
    let response = await axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/apps.manifest.create?manifest=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(manifest))}`, config);
    if (response.data.ok === true) return response.data;
    else {
        console.error('> [error] Invalid could not create app:', response.data.error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

// Verify that a manifest is valid
async function verifyManifest(manifest) {
    const config = {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access.slackConfigToken}` }};
    let response = await axios.get(`https://slack.com/api/apps.manifest.validate?manifest=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(manifest))}`, config);
    if (response.data.ok !== true) {
        console.error('> [error] Manifest did not verify:', response.data.error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

// Main ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function main() {
    // [1] Check token expiration time ------------
    if (access.slackConfigTokenExp < Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000))
        // Token has expired. Refresh it.
        await refreshTokens();

    // [2] Load a manifest from an existing slack app to use as a template ------------
    const templateManifest = await getManifest(TEMPLATE_APP_ID);
    
    // [3] Update URLS and data in the template ------------
    let devApp = { name: 'Review App', slashCommand: '/myslashcommand' };

    templateManifest.settings.interactivity.request_url = `${PUBLIC_URL}/slack/events`;
    templateManifest.settings.interactivity.message_menu_options_url = `${PUBLIC_URL}/slack/events`;
    templateManifest.features.slash_commands[0].url = `${PUBLIC_URL}/slack/events`;
    templateManifest.oauth_config.redirect_urls[0] = `${PUBLIC_URL}/slack/oauth_redirect`;
    templateManifest.settings.event_subscriptions.request_url = `${PUBLIC_URL}/slack/events`;
    templateManifest.display_information.name = devApp.name;
    templateManifest.features.bot_user.display_name = devApp.name;
    templateManifest.features.slash_commands[0].command = devApp.slashCommand;
    
    // [5] Verify that the manifest is still valid ------------
    await verifyManifest(templateManifest);

    // [6] Create our new slack dev application ------------
    devApp.data = await createDevApp(templateManifest);
    console.log(devApp);
}

main();
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking to update Slack applications programatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a method does not exist in the official documentation. There might be an unofficial method - there are quite a few of them actually - but personally I doubt it.

But you don't need this feature for developing Slack apps. Just simulate the POST calls from Slack on your local dev machine with a script and then do a final test together with Slack on your webserver on the Internet.

Comment: There is no general "uri path" of a Slack app as far as I know - there is nothing on Basic Information section. Request URL under Event Subscriptions is the only place I need to change to alter the URL. On practice, it shouldn't anyhow match Redirect URL(s) under OAuth.

Comment: As for development, I need an interactive session of several question-responses (conversation-like) to test against, not single stub calls from a script. Doing entire emulator so I can type values sent via script is definitely an overhead. Plus I need to see how bot-built responses look in Slack, and using two separate places to put request and see response would be inconvenient.

Comment: Its not a big deal to have a simple script with a html form that you can use locally for testing a conversation. Add a log file to see the whole conversion. And for testing the response format and final testing you want a 2nd environment on a webserver which you can use together with Slack. There is a lot of wisdom in separating the dev from the test environment.
You are right regarding the uri path - I will remove that part from my answer.

Comment: I may see advantages of isolating dev environment (e.g. operability if Slack is down), but personally it looks minor to me. I created separate dev app in Slack and get everything exactly like production with minor cost of manually updating request URL once per ngrok restart. As Slack API is evolving (and not yet versioned like FB API), using latest allows to fail fast.